# Materialize input field in Apps Script - Updating/hiding label

Tags: google-apps-script, materialize

I'm using materialize input fields in Google Apps Script UI. I want to have input fields hidden on launch of the form and only become visible  once a control (button or drop down) is changed.

I'm hiding the fields using .style.display='none' which is working fine to hide the input field however the default label text still appears.  I need to hide that as well.
I'm not sure how to change the label text.  I tried .label ="" and .textcontent = "" but not working.  In the materialize documentation it says after making changes you need to use  M.updateTextFields(); to refresh which I did but it doesn't change anything.

```
           <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="aname1" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="aname1">Client 1</label>
      </div>

        <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="aname2" type="text" class="validate">
            <label for="aname2">Client 2</label>
      </div>

      <?!=staff?>


<div class="input-field col s12">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" id="btn">Submit
        <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
</div>
```

--end row-->

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<script>

var drop = document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems);
```

});

```
  var clientNameBox = document.getElementById("cname");
  var accountNameBox = document.getElementById("aname");
  var clientNameBox1 = document.getElementById("aname1");
  var clientNameBox2 = document.getElementById("aname2");
  var dropRateBox = document.getElementById("drop");


  clientNameBox1.label='';
  clientNameBox1.textContent = '';

  clientNameBox1.style.display='none'


    M.updateTextFields();
```

[image]

[image]
Appreciate any thoughts on how to fix this.

Comment: You need to hide the div `<div class="input-field col s12">`

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly! Thanks so much :))) 
Can you add this as an answer so you get the credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide the div .  Probably assign an id and then to hide.

```
divId.style.display='none'
```

or to show.

```
divId.style.display='block'
```